# Fullpage.js extension drag and move not performing drag and move

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

## Followed all guides and dragAndMove is still not dragging or moving

https://jsfiddle.net/davidmitten/n7m2y8du/9/

```js
 new fullpage('#fullpage', {
      autoScrolling: true,
      scrollHorizontally: true,
      dragAndMove: true,
      controlArrows: false,
            sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'orange'],

    });
    //methods
    fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(true);
```

### Steps to reproduce it

- Simply open the link above and try to drag and move. It's in local normally or 127.00.....etc. I use vs-code live server extension normally, but i've also tried running the local file path.

I've followed each guide, tried picking apart the demo. Looked at
others using it and i cannot see why mine isn't functioning as
expected.

The ability to navigate via arrow buttons or via keyboard controls works, it does not work when clicking and dragging and one can presume with a touch event either.

#### Versions

**chrome** - VR: 78.0.3904.108 *(Official Build) (64-bit)*

**mac** - VR: 10.14.6 *Mojave*

**vs-code** - VR: 1.40.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just not including the fullpage.dragAndMove.min.js file.

Comment: Yep. turns out the guy who bought it on my team never read the email and made me debug it for a week! I am the fool in this one.